# The number of re-tweets for twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

How do I get the number of retweets for statuses on my timeline for Twitter4j (latest version). That is:

Status - retweet count to be outputted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you wanna know how many retweet counts each status has, right. There is a method that can be reached via status object to get the actual retweet count of a tweeet.

Look at the following simple code which is printing the tweet id and retweet count for each tweet in the timeline for a given user id:

```
 long userId = 0000000L;

     try 
     {
        ResponseList<Status> statusList = twitterObj.timelines().getUserTimeline(userId);

        for (Status statusItem : statusList)
        {
         System.out.println("Tweet Id : " + statusItem.getId() + ", retweet count: " + statusItem.getRetweetCount());
        }               
     } 
     catch (TwitterException ex) 
     {
        // Do error handling things here
     }
```